# Flash CS, reference root from external class

Tags: flash, reference, document-class

I made this class and I put it in the same package of Timeline.as (the Document Class):

```
package {
    import flash.utils.Timer;
    import flash.events.TimerEvent;

    public class Counter2 extends Timer {

        public function Counter2(delay:Number, repeatCount:int=0) {
            super(delay, repeatCount);
            super.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, timerHandler);
        }

        public override function start():void {
            super.start();
        }
        public override function stop():void {
            super.stop();
        }
        public function timerHandler(evt:TimerEvent) {
            trace(evt.target.currentCount);
        }
    }
}
```

This class is instanciated in Timeline.as constructor. 
Is there any way to reference Timeline(root) from this class? And, if so, how?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The static Stage object is only accessible to objects on the display list. Try creating a public method in your custom timer class & use that to pass (and store) a reference to the stage.... like so:

Document class (or another object currently on the display list):

```
package {
    import TestDependency;
    import flash.display.MovieClip;

    public class Main extends MovieClip
    {
        public var td:TestDependency;

        function Main() {
            td = new TestDependency(1000);
            td.bindToStage(this.stage);
        }
    }
}
```

Your custom class (not in the display list:

```
package {
    import flash.display.Stage;
    import flash.utils.Timer;
    public class TestDependency extends Timer
    {
        private var stageRef:Stage;

        function TestDependency(delay) {
            super(delay);
        }

        public function bindToStage($stageRef:Stage)
        {
            this.stageRef = $stageRef;
            trace(this.stageRef.stageWidth);
        }
    }
}
```